# Convertir string a nombre de variable

Tags: python, math

Tengo un pequeño programa que funciona como una calculadora en notación posfija, entonces tengo implementado ciertas funciones trigonométricas, para ello, uso la librería math.
He generado una lista de las operaciones que quiero hacer con:
`dir(math)`. Pero claro, mi programa después, devuelve un string con la operación que quiere realizar, por ejemplo un string `cos` y un valor para calcularlo. Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de por ejemplo pasar dicho string al nombre propio de math, por ejemplo algo como: `'math.' + 'cos'`. Y de ahí pasar a que devuelva la variable de math, es posible?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa un diccionario en el que la clave sea la cadena y el valor la función del módulo `math`, de otro módulo o una propia creada por ti:

```
import math

def minimo_comun_multiplo(a, b):
    pass

operaciones = {
    "cos": math.cos,
    "acos": math.acos,
    "atan": math.atan,
    "sin": math.sin,
    "tan": math.atan,
    "sqrt": math.sqrt,
    "mcm": minimo_comun_multiplo
    }
```

Puedes también establecer varias cadenas o alias para una misma función si lo necesitas:

```
operaciones = {
    "cos": math.cos,
    "coseno": math.cos,
    ...
}
```

Con tu diccionario definido, solo debes usar la cadena para buscar la función correspondiente en él y directamente llamarla con los operandos correspondientes:

```
operacion = "sin"
operador = 45
funcion = operaciones.get(operacion)
if funcion is None:
    print("Operación no disponible")
else:
    print(funcion(operador))
```

Si existe la posibilidad de que se introduzcan operaciones no válidas o no disponibles usar `dict.get` junto a un condicional es una buena idea para solventar estos casos.

Si quieres generar el diccionario de forma automática puedes tirar del módulo `inspect`:

```
import math
import inspect

operaciones = dict(inspect.getmembers(math))
```

esto incluye ciertos métodos y atributos especiales que no vas a necesitar como `__name__`, `__doc__`, `__file__`, etc. Para no incluirlos basta con usar un condicional a la hora de generar el diccionario:

```
import math
import inspect


operaciones = {nombre: func for nombre, func in inspect.getmembers(math)
               if not nombre.startswith("__")}
```

La otra opción es usar [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) cada vez que necesitas una operación:

```
import math

operacion = "sin"
operador = 45

funcion = getattr(math, operacion, None)
if funcion is None:
    print("Operación no disponible")
else:
    print(funcion(operador))
```

Comment: Sí, eso funciona, pero estoy buscando una forma de no tener que introducir las 60 funciones disponibles con math.

Comment: @DecowVR he editado la respuesta, mira al final. Debería ser lo que buscas.

Comment: Nota que la realidad es más complejo. Hay funciones con uno, dos o un número variable de parámetros. Por ejemplo `math.log(x)` emplea la base `e` y `math.log(x, 2)` emplea la base `2`. `max` puede tener múltiples números. También hay constantes como `math.e` y `math.pi`.  Y hay que tener en cuenta que muchas funciones tiene el input limitado, como `math.sqrt` solo funciona con números positivos y `math.asin` necesita un número entre -1 y 1. Y el primer argumento de `math.pow` tiene que ser positivo excepto cuando el segundo argumento es un numero entero, ...

Comment: @JohanC si, eso es cierto, pero eso debería solventarlo el parser en si o manejar excepciones en todo caso al llamar a cada función si se usa un codominio incorrecto (como el mencionado asin) por ejemplo. He restringido la respuesta a cómo referenciar la función mediante su nombre en forma de str, sin entrar en el ámbito del parser, que por regla general son bastante complejos si se quieren implementar en condiciones... :)